# How to make or get corpus of financial documents

Tags: nlp

I am working on a document classification problem for financial reports/documents. Is there a ready made corpus for this ? I found a couple of use cases, but they all made their own corpus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will more than likely have to create your own corpus. I had a similar task and manually creating such a corpus would be too tedious. As a result I created [News Corpus Builder](http://skillachie.github.io/news-corpus-builder/) a python module that would allow you to quickly develop a corpus based on your particular interest of topics.

The module allows you to generate your own corpus and store the text and associated label in sqlite or as flat files.

```
from news_corpus_builder import NewsCorpusGenerator

# Location to save generated corpus
corpus_dir = '/Users/skillachie/finance_corpus'

# Save results to sqlite or  files per article 
ex = NewsCorpusGenerator(corpus_dir,'sqlite')

# Retrieve 50 links related to the search term dogs and assign a category of   Pet to the retrieved links
links = ex.google_news_search('dogs','Pet',50)

# Generate and save corpus
ex.generate_corpus(links)
```

More details on my [blog](http://skillachie.com/2015/09/06/automatically-generating-a-financial-news-corpus-using-news-corpus-builder/)

The finance corpus is available for download [here](https://github.com/skillachie/binaryNLP/blob/master/corpora/finance_corpus.db) . The corpus has the following categories:

- Policy (licenses , regulation, SEC, monetary, fed,    monetary,fiscal,imf)
- International  Finance( global finance, IMF,    ECB, trouble in Greece, RMB devaluation)
- Economy (GDP, Jobs,    unemployment, housing, economy) Raising Capital(ipo, equity)
- Real    Estate
- Mergers &  Acquisitions (merger,acquisitions)
- Oil(oil,oil    prices,natural gas price)
- Commodities (commodities,gold ,silver)
- Fraud(insider trading, ponzi scheme, finance fraud)
- Litigation    (company litigation, company settlement,)
- Earning Reports

Comment: No problem. You might also be interested in this notebook https://github.com/skillachie/nlpArea51/blob/master/Financial_News_Text_Classification.ipynb

Comment: Sir or lady, you are a hero of the day. Not only your link to the finance corpus helped me, but your module would also allow to tune the model even further. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Reuters-21578 corpus.  http://www.daviddlewis.com/resources/testcollections/reuters21578/

It is a basic corpus for test classification.